# Can I use a member of an object that requires a cast without using a temporary variable?

Tags: c#, casting

I'd like to know if there is some way to use the method of a casted object without creating a new variable. In other word, is there a way to do this:

```
abstract class event { }

class loop : event
{ 
    public int a;
}

static void main ()
{
     loop l = new loop();
     l.a = 5;
     event e = l; //supposing that 

     System.Console.WriteLine( (loop) (e).a );//error

     loop lcast = (loop) e;
     System.Console.WriteLine( lcast.a );//no error
}
```

Can I access the field `a` without creating a temporary variable (`lcast`)?

Comment: As an aside, the code you've posted isn't valid because `event` is a keyword... and C# uses a method called `Main` as an entry point, not `main`. Further, `loop` doesn't follow normal .NET naming conventions, and your code is badly formatted. Yes, we can still understand your question - but it would be a *better* question if you'd remove these distractions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem with operator precedence. `.` has a higher precedence than a cast, so this:

```
(loop) (e).a
```

is being treated as:

```
(loop) ((e).a)
```

You want to cast and then use the result in the member access - so you need to bind the cast more tightly than the `.` for member access:

```
((loop) e).a
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/6a71f45d.aspx) for the full C# operator precedence rules.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. There is a problem with your parenthesis. Following should work

```
System.Console.WriteLine(((loop)e).a);
```

Note: I can see you're using public fields, avoid it in your production code. [Use properties instead](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx).

And `event` is a reserved word in c#, your code won't compile. While posting code it is better to test yourself once.